# How can I point to previous versions of a nightly package feed? (AspNet Core)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dnx

We have recently run into the issue related to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1426) breaking change in ASP.NET RC2.

We are using the package feed (https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext) and RC2 and can now no longer use DNX and visual studio. What we need is a way to avoid having to switch to VS code and redoing our entire build server. The obvious solution to me is to point to the package versions from before this change was made but I am not sure how to do this, or if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't keep multiple versions of the dev packages on any public feed; it's only the latest version. You have two options:

1. Switch back to rc1 packages (they are available on nuget)
2. Build the packages that you depend on yourself from the sources on GitHub